# Is there a way to omit the lifetimes for the trait here?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm fighting with lifetimes again. Or actually, I kinda won the fight but I'm not sure if the outcome is the intended way to handle it.

Say I have a struct with two lifetimes: `Inner<'a, 'b>`. Now I want to write a trait that defines a `new(inner: &Inner) -> Self` method. The implementer should be free to store the reference to `Inner` internally and define other methods to work on it.

I came up with this (it works!) but I have a couple of questions

```
struct Inner<'a, 'b>{
    foo: &'a str,
    bar: &'b str
}

trait Worker<'data, 'a, 'b> {
    fn new (inner: &'data Inner<'a, 'b>) -> Self;
    fn work_with_inner () { println!("works on inner");}
}

struct SomeWorker<'inner, 'a:'inner, 'b:'inner> {
    inner: &'inner Inner<'a, 'b>
}

impl<'data, 'a, 'b> Worker<'data, 'a, 'b> for SomeWorker<'data, 'a, 'b> {
    fn new (inner: &'data Inner<'a, 'b>) -> Self {
        SomeWorker {
            inner: inner
        }
    }
}

fn main () {
}
```

Playpen: http://is.gd/A3ol4w

1. in terms of lifetimes, can this be simplified? In particular, I was wondering if the trait really needs to define all those lifetimes or if there's a way to only define them on the struct?
2. if there's no way to omit the lifetimes on the trait does that mean it's a best practice to specify all possible lifetimes on a trait to have the most flexibility for the implementer? I mean, if the `SomeWorker` struct would not want to store the reference to `Inner`, the whole thing, including the trait, could be much simpler.

See, no lifetimes at all.

```
struct Inner<'a, 'b>{
    foo: &'a str,
    bar: &'b str
}

trait Worker {
    fn new (inner: &Inner) -> Self;
    fn work_with_inner () { println!("works on inner");}
}

struct SomeWorker;

impl Worker for SomeWorker {
    fn new (inner: &Inner) -> Self {
        SomeWorker
    }
}

fn main () {
}
```

Playpen: http://is.gd/NzigjX

This is why I'm asking myself if as a trait author I should assume that all methods that take references may end up being stored on a field by the trait implementer and therefore I need to specify all the lifetimes on the trait to make that possible for implementors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no one-size-fits-all solution. As a trait author, you have to think about what you are attempting to do and what you want to achieve.

If you want the ability to correlate a values lifetime with the lifetime parameters of a struct, then you must put the lifetime on the trait. This would *generally* be done because your trait has multiple methods that are expected to operate on the same value with lifetimes. This might something like a getter / setter pair. In some code I have written, I'm passing in `&str` references that I hold onto for a while before "finalizing" them. If you need to store the reference for any reason, then you will need to have lifetimes on the trait.

In your case, you have a constructor method that needs to know of the lifetimes if the struct does. You can separate that function from the rest of the trait, if it's truly distinct. In your example, the `work_with_inner` method doesn't accept a `self` argument, so that would be **very** distinct. If you used `self` but didn't need to interact with the lifetimes from `Inner`, it can still help:

```
trait WorkerBuilder<'a, 'b> {
    fn new(inner: Inner<'a, 'b>) -> Self;
}

trait Worker {
    fn do_work(&self);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Inner<'a, 'b>{
    foo: &'a str,
    bar: &'b str,
}

// This does track `Inner`
#[derive(Debug)]
struct SomeWorker<'a, 'b>(Inner<'a, 'b>);

impl<'a, 'b> WorkerBuilder<'a, 'b> for SomeWorker<'a, 'b> {
    fn new(inner: Inner<'a, 'b>) -> SomeWorker<'a, 'b> {
        SomeWorker(inner)
    }
}

impl<'a, 'b> Worker for SomeWorker<'a, 'b> {
    fn do_work(&self) { println!("Doing work, {:?}", self.0) }
}

// This doesn't track `Inner`
#[derive(Debug)]
struct DumbWorker;

impl<'a, 'b> WorkerBuilder<'a, 'b> for DumbWorker {
    fn new(inner: Inner<'a, 'b>) -> DumbWorker {
        DumbWorker
    }
}

fn main () {}
```

You'll see I also applied one thing that you *can* do to reduce the number of lifetimes. If you have a struct that is just references (or references and other small `Copy` types), there is no need to pass a reference to *that* struct. References are copyable, and tracking the lifetime of the containing struct isn't useful.

---

Editorial — I don't feel like "constructor" methods are generally useful in a trait. You often want to provide a different set or parameters, which is why you have different types in the first place. Perhaps your real code is using something other than a constructor in the trait though.

Comment: Great answer as usual! The missing `&self` was a sloppy me with the example. It kinda led me to another question haha http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374149/what-type-annotations-does-rust-want-for-this-ufcs-call