# What type annotations does Rust want for this UFCS call?

Tags: rust, traits

Sorry, I'm probably missing something **super** obvious. I wonder why I can't call my trait method like this. Shouldn't this be the standard UFCS.

```
trait FooPrinter {
    fn print ()  {
        println!("hello");
    }
}

fn main () {
    FooPrinter::print();
}
```

Playpen: http://is.gd/ZPu9iP

I get the following error

```
error: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_ : FooPrinter`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call a trait method without specifying on which implementation you wish to call it. It doesn't matter that the method has a default implementation.

An actual UFCS call looks like this:

```
trait FooPrinter {
    fn print()  {
        println!("hello");
    }
}

impl FooPrinter for () {}

fn main () {
    <() as FooPrinter>::print();
}
```

[playground](http://is.gd/fAyAWm)

If you don't need polymorphism on this method, move it to a `struct` or `enum`, or make it a global function.

Comment: Interesting. So basically you can use `UFCS` only when the trait method takes some sort of `self` like here? http://is.gd/36zFFZ

Comment: Oh, it sure is possible. See my edit. I didn't go into details because your example was so minimal I thought you were using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Oh, that's even more interesting! I'm really just poking around with language features ;)